# Struct pointer in struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm having trouble understanding struct pointers within struct. Could you try to explain it to me or recommend some interesting reading that explain the concept? I don't know if it is a too general question, in which case I'm sorry.

Example:

```
struct person{
    struct person* mother;
    struct person* father;
    int birthday;
};

struct person john;
struct person alice;
struct person rachael;
john.birthday = 1988;
alice.mother = &rachael;
alice.mother->birthday = 1970;
```

Comment: What don't you understand about it?

Comment: I don't understand very well what's mean the part about "alice.mother->birthday = 1970" and how the syntax is like that

Comment: When you have a pointer you need to de-reference it using either `*` before it or `->` after it. A local structure uses `.` to access properties.

Comment: What don't you understand about that part?

Comment: There's nothing different about a pointer in a struct and a pointer in an ordinary variable. You use them exactly the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you have a struct that has pointer references to the same kind of struct, this is legal in C, whereas including a whole struct (and the memory for the elements) wouldn't work because it is recursive...

```
struct person{
int age; // sizeof(int) bytes
person mom; // sizeof(int) + sizeof person, which is sizeof int bytes + sizeof person...
};
```

that wouldn't work, because it would take infinite memory to store.

so you have to store a pointer to an instance, which is a variable that stores the address of an instance, or NULL (in a well behaved program it probably shouldn't be any other value)

```
struct person{
int age; // sizeof(int) bytes
person * mom; // sizeof (*person)...
};
```

so now we can start doing things

```
person QueenMother; // these have storage, but are garbage data
person QueenElizabethII;
```

both of those are on stack, all of the memory they use is used right there. as you pointed out you can make an assignment:

```
QueenElizabethII.mom = &QueenMother;
```

so the pointer to mom is the address of QueenMother... that works, now if you want to set the QueenMother's age through the QueenElizabethII instance you can.

```
(*QueenElizabethII.mom).age = 102; // dereference and dot accessor.
//which you could also write as
QueenElizabethII.mom->age = 102;  // pointer to member accessor
```

now if we wanted to re-write this all dynamically we could do something like:

```
struct person{
int age; // sizeof(int) bytes
person * mom; // sizeof(int) + sizeof (*person)...
};

person * QueenMother; // these dont have storage yet; 
person * QueenElizabethII;

QueenElizabethII = malloc(sizeof(person)); // now we have storage, but the data is garbage... we can initialize it to 0 with memset, or bzero; or you can do this:
QueenMother = calloc(1,sizeof(person)); // calloc is like malloc, but it zero's the data in the return

QueenElizabethII->mother = QueenMother; // now this syntax is smoother
QueenElizabethII->age = 94;
QueenElizabethII->mother->age=102; // if you are so inclined.
```

one thing you always need to be aware of with this strategy is that you need to check that the pointers actually point somewhere or you will crash...

```
if(QueenElizabethII->mother){
    QueenElizabethII->mother->age=102; // now that is safe... probably
}
```

and I should add when you are done with the memory you should free it:

```
free(QueenElizabethII);
free(QueenMother);
```

Otherwise you have a leak

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

From your comment, this part:

```
alice.mother->birthday = 1970;
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
(*(alice.mother)).birthday = 1970;
```

---

`alice.mother` is of type `struct person*`

`(*(alice.mother))` dereferences the pointer, so the type is `struct person`

`(*(alice.mother)).birthday` gives you access to the birthday field of the `struct person`, so now you can assign a value to it.

---

C just provides syntactic sugar in the form of `->` so that you don't have to write the alternative, which is an ugly mess